# Conversion of $ \nabla $ to $ \nabla' $(please watch video shown, in the time range provided) (doubt explained below video link)

Tags: calculus, differential

Video: https://youtu.be/JCfhChaJvCo (Doubt is in the time range 26:50 to 28:30 )

**A bit of background**

I am given to understand that when the lecturer in the video says that [video time: 26:57] $ \nabla $ is the vector differential operator on $ \vec r$  he imples the following: 
$ \nabla = \frac \partial {\partial x} \hat \imath+\frac \partial {\partial y}\hat \jmath+\frac \partial {\partial z}  \hat k$

$\vec r=x\hat \imath+y\hat\jmath+z\hat k$
$r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$
where $ \hat \imath, \hat \jmath, \hat k $ are the unit vectors in the x,y,z directions respectively.

(Correct me if my understanding is wrong)

**Doubts:**

1.how does the person convert $ \nabla $ to $ \nabla' $ in his "mathematical trick"? [Video time- 28:30] 
 
2.Does $ \nabla' $ mean something other than $ \nabla $?
3.Is $\nabla'$ the vector differential operatior for $\vec r'$ and if so,what would be the [i,j,k] expanded form of $\nabla'$?
3.is it possible to freely convert between different variations on $\nabla$?
4.What textbook would give me clarity and a deeper look into this $\nabla$ conversion?

Comment: You did not link to the specific time.  You should right-click the video and select "copy video URL at current time".

Comment: Or, just tell us what the time is

Comment: the time is a range starting from 26:50 ending at 28:30

Answer (score 0):

The sequence of equalities in question (leaving out the superfluous constants, with the understanding that $E$'s and $r,r'$ are vectors) is as follows:
$$
E(r) = \int_V \rho(r') \frac{r - r'}{|r-r'|^3}d^3r'\\
(\nabla_r \cdot E)(r) = \nabla_r\cdot  \int_V \rho(r') \frac{r - r'}{|r-r'|^3}d^3r'\\
= \int_V \rho(r') \nabla_r \cdot \left(\frac{r - r'}{|r-r'|^3}\right)d^3r'
\\
\overset{!!!}= -\int_V \rho(r') \nabla_{r'} \cdot \left(\frac{r - r'}{|r-r'|^3}\right)d^3r'
$$
The fact that we are using in this last equality is as follows:

> **Claim:** For any $f:\Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$, we have 
>   $$
> \nabla_r \cdot f(r-r') = -\nabla_{r'} \cdot f(r-r')
> $$
>   Or, to write the same thing differently,
>   $$
> \nabla_r \cdot f(x-x',y-y',z-z') = -\nabla_{r'} \cdot f(x-x',y-y',z-z')
> $$

So first, what does the notation mean?  Note that $r = (x,y,z)$ is the argument (input) of our function $E$, whereas $r' = (x',y',z')$ is a dummy variable for intgeration.

As an example: if we were to define the single-variable function 
$g(x) = \int_0^1 t (x-t)^2\,dt$, then $x$ plays the role analogous to $r$, while $t$ plays the role analogous to $r'$.

Now, given an expression involving both $r$ and $r'$, we define
$$
\nabla_r \cdot F(x,y,z,x',y',z') = 
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} + 
\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} + 
\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\\
\nabla_{r'} \cdot F(x,y,z,x',y',z') = 
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x'} + 
\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} + 
\frac{\partial F}{\partial z'}
$$
Now, perhaps you can see (as a consequence of the chain rule) that my above claim holds.  We can now apply this fact to the integrand in order to reach that last equality.

Comment: Let me know if anything is unclear.  Do note that I have left out the $\vec{}$'s for my own convenience; every $r$ and $r'$ here is a vector.

Comment: Nothing is unclear sir. Thank you very much! This was most helpful. Nowhere in any textbook is  $\nabla$ given as a function of a vector. Hence my doubt. Please suggest a multivariate and vector calculus book. It would greatly help

Comment: Note that $\nabla$ on its own denotes an operator on a scalar-valued function ($\nabla V$ is the **gradient** of $V$) and $\nabla \cdot $ denotes an operator on a vector-valued function (so $\nabla \cdot \vec{E}$ denotes the **divergence** of $\vec{E}$).  See the latter part of [these notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/CurlDivergence.aspx) for more on the divergence of a vector field.  I don't have a textbook reference off the top of my head.

Comment: does $\nabla$ on its own denote the operator $\nabla_r$, ie $ \nabla_r = \frac \partial {\partial x} \hat \imath+\frac \partial {\partial y}\hat \jmath+\frac \partial {\partial z}  \hat k$?

Comment: Yes. I only added the subscript $r$ to distinguish it from $\nabla_{r'} = \nabla'$.

Comment: Thanks, all cleared up now :)